# Bundling css and js with OWIN

Tags: asp.net, owin, bundling-and-minification

In ASP.NET application we could bundle up css and js as show in following code.

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
```

Is there any OWIN middleware which can minify and bundle css and js?

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not interested in adopting a framework that does anything other than minification, bundling and perhaps compression I was hoping for a single-responsibility middleware component. There doesn't seem to be many. I stumbled upon [Ominify](https://github.com/rmacfie/Ominify) by [Robert Macfie](https://robert.macfie.se/), it provides a simple and familiar interface:

```
x.AddPackage(new YuiCssPackage("/content/css/minified-css").With(
    "/content/css/normalize-3.0.0.css", // Actual files
    "/content/css/font-awesome-4.0.3.css",
    "/content/css/layout.css"));

x.AddPackage(new YuiJsPackage("/content/js/minified-js").With(
    "/content/js/jquery-2.1.0.js",
    "/content/js/angular-1.2.0.js"));
```

The only concern here is the use of [Yui Compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/). For those who are indifferent on the use of Yui and/or have no project constraints this may be a viable solution. If anyone is aware of how to remove the dependency on Yui please share, I believe [Ominify](https://github.com/rmacfie/Ominify) could solve the need for many developers with the same question as the OP.

#### References

- [Yui Compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/)
- [Ominify](https://github.com/rmacfie/Ominify)
- [Robert Macfie](https://robert.macfie.se/)

Answer (score 0):

This might help. I'm assuming you want to do this without IIS and System.Web
http://responsiblecoder.com/2014/04/nancy-on-owin-bundling-and-minification/

Comment: The site is gone. [Provide context for links](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) next time...